# Efficient visualisation in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, probability-theory

I have data (generated by an algorithm I wrote for it) for a random process which consists of coalescing and branching random walks on a finite space that I would like to visualize using python and probably something from matplotlib.

The data look like this:

A list of lists the of states of the process at times when something changes (a walk moves to an empty spot, coalesces with another one or a new particle is born), so something like this (let's say the process lives on {0,1,2,3,4}:

`[[0,1,2,0,2],...,[1,0,2,2,0]]`, so at the beginning I start with the process having particles at positions 1,2 and 4 (there are two different kinds of particles so that "1" indicates the presence of a first type and "2" of the second, whole "0" means nothing there)

And I have also the list of events that alter the process, so a list of lists of the form

```
[place,time,type]
```

so I know what happens where and at what time (which corresponds to writing appropriate marks in the graphical representation, for example an arrow to the left if the event was that a particle moved to the left).

I wrote something like this :

```
import pylab as P
P.plot(-spacebound,0,spacebound,maxtime)
while something in the process:
    current=listofevents.pop(0)
    for i that are nonempty at current time:
        P.arrow() in a way corresponding to the data

P.show()
```

This works, but it is extremely slow so that if I have a big process it takes an enormous amount of time to make this visualization (while generating the process data takes a few seconds at most for rather extreme parameters - a big space, time and a high rate of particle births which means a a lot of events changing the process often).

I am pretty sure using arrows like this is pretty idiotic, but since I've only visualized things in R so far (I could of course simply export my data from python and visualize them in R but I want to avoid that) I am also very green at doing this in Python.

I tried some googling, found out about matplotlib and looked at some tutorials there and apart from the arrows I also tried just visualizing the states of the process (without the events) by looping `plt.scatter()` over all the states, but while this is slightly faster, it is still extremely slow and it also looks messy.

So how would I plot this in a sensible way? Even a link to something like "learn to do plotting in Python properly" is welcome as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question to contain an actual question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

matplotlib is not for interactive plotting. It used for generating a article-quality plots. For interactive plots you could try to use Chaco or other libs. The Chaco ideology is to create a plot and link it with the data. As you update the data you get your chart updated automatically.